# SharePoint Learning Kit database error

Tags: sql-server, learning-kit, error

I have installed the Microsoft SharePoint Learning Kit but when I'm configuring the SLK it gives the following error:

*'CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.'*

Does anybody know what causes this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user which your are running under (or the SLK is running under) does not have appropriate permissions to the SQL Server instance.  This means that it cannot create a database on that server.

Are you specifiying a SQL Server for the configuration to use?  Are you also specifying SQL authentication?   If so then the account you are giving does not have permissions.  If you are not specifying and auth mechanism or you are using Windows Auth then the account which you are logged in as will probably need the appropriate permissions.  If this is the case then try logging in as an account which has rights.

Comment: its working now after giving the appropriate permissions. Thanks.